# Staircase of Numbers using Nested Loops

Tags: java, loops

So I am trying to use ONLY nested loops to output this:

```
    1
   2
  3
 4
5
```

This is what I've tried:

```
public class apples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
     }
}
```

It outputs:

```
1
 2
  3
   4
    5
```

Finding it hard to find out how to format it in such a way.:(

Comment: The task might be more easily tackled by first print-ing spaces and then println the number: forming one single line.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm just wondering if these mistakes are okay to make after 1 month of coding? I feel a little upset that I wasn't able to do that.

Comment: That is quite normal: the same holds for math. Introducing a mentally reflected model: combining aspects and toying with them; that is established with repeated practicing. No effort involved, like solving Rubik's cube. You can improve the learning curve by thinking in concepts: "printing a single line = print spaces and print number, println".

Answer (score 3):

Change to:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 5; j >= i; j--) {
       System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

The best thing to do when facing questions like this one, is to debug your first attempt and see the flow of your program. Then you can easily make changes because you really understand how it works.

Comment: Not really. This will print 5 4 3 2 1 instead of 1 2 3 4 5. In fact the change from OP's code is simpler(only 2 symbols to be precise).

Comment: I thought that's what OP wants, will edit my answer.

Comment: now this version makes no sense. How many iterations will  `for (int j = i; j >= i; j--)` do?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev While you were typing that I fixed my code :) Sorry, I have no IDE.. I'm almost sure it works now.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm just wondering if these mistakes are okay to make after 1 month of coding? I feel a little upset that I wasn't able to do that.

Comment: @dragonmasainit They're ok to make after 10 years of coding.

Comment: @dragonmasainit I mean it :) really.

Comment: Everyone makes silly mistakes from time to time. The only difference is we make the mistakes in unit tests instead of in `main`

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, but you need to work on the number of spaces being printed. Try to write on a piece of paper the number of spaces you actually print for each iteration and the number you need to print according to the target. There is a very easy relation.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want nested loops try this:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int n = 5;
       for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = n - i; j > 0; j--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
 class apples {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
       for (int j = 5; j >i ; j--) {
         System.out.print(" ");
       }
       System.out.println(i);
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            for(int j=1;j<=5-i;j++)
                System.out.print(" ");

            System.out.println(i);

    }
```